# Teachers and Students sitting in a line with a condition

Tags: combinatorics

A class consists of three teachers (Mr. P, Ms. Q, Ms. R) and six students (Ali, Bob, Cal, Dee, Amy, Fay). How many ways can they sit in a line of 9 chairs if we have the property that between any two teachers there are exactly two students?

The correct answer is supposed to be 12,960 ways, but I cannot determine this answer. My main assumption is that there are three teachers, the two of these students will have to sit alone on the sides of the teachers. Like so:

S T S S T S S T S

My attempt:
$6\times3\times5\times4\times2\times3\times2\times1\times1$ which equals $4320$.

Comment: You can also have SSTSSTSST or TSSTSSTSS.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. My mind locked me into thinking that every two students needed a teacher to the left and right of them, but it was okay if there was lone students. I made the question harder than it needed to be.

Comment: @Ludwigthestud:  that gives you exactly the missing factor $3$